# laravel trying to get property of non-object from a model inside a controller

Tags: php, laravel

So im trying to check if an authenticated user is already following the user, however im getting this error.

> Trying to get property of non-object
>
> if ($followers->user_id == auth()->id()){
>                   return true;
>               }
>
> 8 "Trying to get property of non-object"
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elipost/app/MyFollow.php" 34

I'm not sure if im using this method below properly.

`$query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);`

**UserController.php**

```
public function getProfile($user)
{  
    $users = User::with(['posts.likes' => function($query) {
                        $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                    }, 'follow','follow.follower'])

                    ->with(['followers' => function($query) {
                        $query->with('follow.followedByMe');
                        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);


                    }])->where('name','=', $user)->get();

    $user = $users->map(function(User $myuser){


        $myuser['followedByMe'] = $myuser->followers->count() == 0 ? false : true;
             // $myuser['followedByMe'] = $myuser->followers->count() == 0 ? false : true;
        dd($owl = $myuser['followedByMe']);


        return $myuser;

    });
```

**User.php**

```
public function follow()
{   
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow');
}
```

**MyFollow**(model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanFollow;
use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanBeFollowed;

class MyFollow extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CanFollow, CanBeFollowed;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'followable_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'followables';

    public function follower()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'followable_id');
    }

    public function followedByMe()
    {
        foreach($this->follower as $followers) {
            if ($followers->user_id == auth()->id()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you please show your stack trace?

Comment: i just updated it

Comment: where is the `followers` relations that you have used `->with(['followers'` ?

Comment: Good question, i have no idea, i think its supposed to be `follow` right ?

Comment: first of all what is `followable_id`, in `MyFollow` model ? just wanted to know what are the fields in `MyFollow` model and which table they reference

Comment: not sure, but i dont think it has to with the followable_id

Comment: what does it store  in `followable_id` ?

Comment: it stores an integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174617/discussion-between-rkj-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`followedByMe` is incorrectly looping a single record. Try the following changes:

```
public function followedByMe()
{
    return $this->follower->getKey() === auth()->id();
}
```

Since `follower` is a `belongsTo` relationship, it will only return at most one record, not a collection.

The `map` function is also incorrectly using array access on a model. You cannot use `['followedByMe']` on an object, to access a property you need to use `->` notation as in `$myuser->followedByMe`. The following shows how to use the map function:

```
$user = $users->map(function(User $myuser){
    return ['followedByMe' => $myuser->followers->count() == 0];
});
```

Which would return an array similar to:

```
[
    ['followedByMe' => true],
    ['followedByMe' => false],
    ['followedByMe' => true],
]
```

Comment: i get `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean` and i need to determine ifs true or false.

Comment: im still getting `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean`

Comment: More information such as a stack trace and/or line number would be helpful.

Comment: `$relation = $this->getRelation($name);
 
        $relation->addEagerConstraints($models);
 
        $constraints($relation);`

Comment: Does that help ?

Comment: No, does the Laravel log file show a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: `local.ERROR: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean {"userId":3,"email":"sammywam343@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elipost/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:522)"} []`

Comment: does that help ?

Comment: Not really, you should be looking for something that indicates which line number from you code the exception is coming from. Also, Add the debugging information to the answer in a formatted way, it's hard to read a bunch of code in comments.

Comment: how do i find the stack trace ?

Comment: It's typically printed in the log file in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: is the most recent one, all the way at the bottom ? even then i don't think thats the most relevant one.

Comment: Yes the log messages are appended to the end of the file. And you may be correct, if other messages are printed after the relevant exception then it will be before those.

Comment: i havent been able to find anything relevant to the problem im so sorry man

Comment: Well you can always use the old tried and true method, use `dd()` at various places in the code to locate where the problem is coming from and then go from there.

Comment: i can just delete log file, and it will show me the most recent one. be back in a few.